# The problem of finding div class number with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to find a number of div classes and add a code after class two.

**UPDATE**

It works just as it should when writing another code instead of Google ad codes.

```
 <script>
  $(function()
 {
var say = $('.panel-footer.clearfix').length;
if(say >= 3){
     $('.panel-footer.clearfix')[1].after('<script async 
 src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-3767785488130692"
 data-ad-slot="3213073317"></ins>
 <script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>');
}
   });
```

but it doesn't work. The code is running at the bottom of the page instead of the number two div.

Comment: Have you tried $('.panel-footer clearfix')[1]?

Comment: try changing to :eq(1). I think your problem is confusion over finding the 2nd element in a 0-based array

Comment: Do you hope the PHP code will be immediately executed ?

Comment: cah you show dive structure

Comment: I tried it. but the code is not working. array number does not matter. because (0), (1), (2) there are 10 "panel - footer clearfix" on the page, but not after all. Adding to the bottom of the page. @DiegoRosales

Comment: I tried it. but the code is not working. array number does not matter. because (0), (1), (2) there are 10 "panel - footer clearfix" on the page, but not after all. Adding to the bottom of the page. @ControlAltDel

Comment: please see above update. It works just as it should when writing another code instead of Google ad codes. @JCH77

Comment: We need the HTML to answer you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-footer clearfix"></div>
<div class="panel-footer clearfix"></div>
<div class="panel-footer clearfix"></div>
<script>
function insert_adsbygoogle(arg1) {
  //https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7477845?hl=en
  (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3767785488130692",
    data_ad_slot: "3213073317",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
  var say = $('.panel-footer.clearfix').length;
  if (say >= 3) {
    $('.panel-footer.clearfix').eq(1).after("<div id=write_container_for_adsbygoogle></div>");

    // container is where you want the ad to be inserted

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.setAttribute("async", "");
    script.src = "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
    $('#write_container_for_adsbygoogle').after(script);
  } else if (arg1 === "first") {
    $(window).on("load", insert_adsbygoogle);
  }
}
insert_adsbygoogle("first");
</script>
```

Comment: this not work. I guess we should call the script code after the after code in another way. @Hors Sujet

Comment: @BatuhanAygün do you try load event ?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to use it. @Hors Sujet

Comment: no its not working. <script> tags do not work correctly.

Comment: this not working. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZQ84WHKXD1O  error or not responding. @Hors Sujet

Comment: @BatuhanAygün This work try in .html file or in your website. You can't try the google code in iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Aussuming that clearfix is class name

```
 <script>
         $(function()
     {
        var say = $('.panel-footer.clearfix').length();
         if(say >= 3){
         $('.panel-footer.clearfix:eq(2)').after('<?php echo 
        get_option("my_php_code");?>');
     }
      });
     </script>
```

Comment: Why 2? Documentation : "Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these selectors reflect that fact. This is why $( "xxxxxx:eq(1)" ) selects the second." https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#eq1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the indexation of the array returned by jquery, also length is not a function so it's just `length`.

```
$(function()
{
    var say = $('.panel-footer clearfix').length;
    if(say >= 3){
       $('.panel-footer clearfix')[1].after('<?php echo get_option("my_php_code");?>');
    }
 });
```

If clearfix is a class you must use: `$('.panel-footer.clearfix')` as remarked in  another comment.

Comment: this code works, but "my_php_code" in the section that says google adsense code from the database. and I think I'm getting an error in syntax error style.

Comment: ` <script>
$(function()
{
    var say = $('.panel-footer.clearfix').length;
    if(say >= 3){
       $('.panel-footer.clearfix')[1].after('<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- mobil üst -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3767785488130692"
     data-ad-slot="3213073317"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>');
    }
 });
     </script>`

Comment: It works just as it should when writing another code instead of Google ad codes.